# Raspberry pi 3B wont boot from USB with correct OTP settings

Tags: pi-3, usb, boot-issues

I'm trying to boot my Raspberry Pi 3B (not 3B +) from a USB flash drive.

- I've added the `program_usb_boot_mode=1` line the `/boot/config.txt`
- I've changed the right bits in the OTP and checked it:

  `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd otp_dump | grep 17:
  17:3020000a`
- I've flashed the USB with Raspbian noob and I've tried it as well
  with Lite, however neither of the two have resulted in a boot yet.

I've tried booting with and without the SD card installed, with the 'noobs' stretch and with the 'Lite' stretch.

I have tried to look up some documentation but the official [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md) page doesn't give any other information

The raspberry pi does boot from as SD card and the USB is fully functional.

I have heard of some errors where the rainbow screen was shown however this isn't the case with me, the green led stays off and nothing appears on my monitor.

Do you maybe have a clue what's going on and how it can be fixt?

--Edit: I have a charger that I believe should work, however I'm not very familiar with chargers but says the following:

```
5V = 3A

or 9V = 1.5A

or 12V = 1.2A
```

--edit:
I use an American charger whist I live in the EU, however it can handle both 50 and 60 hertz and its plugged in to an adapter which can handle 10A - 250V ~ so I don't think the charger could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got two suggestions. Both of them might be long shots, but here goes:

1. *Check your power supply*. The Pi needs more than the standard USB standard requires, so you may get unexpected results if you're using a weaker one. There is no harm in using a 5V 2.5A power supply since the Pi will only take the current it needs.
2. *Try a different brand of USB flash drive*. Flash drives seem like they are all the same since we use them the same way, but there are differences under the hood which can cause problems in rare cases. See [this forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1176984#p1294668).

Comment: Thank you, it was the USB flash drive, when I switched to a different USB it booted without any problems whatsoever